# Convert sql to Hibernate createCriteria

Tags: sql, hibernate

I would like to convert to Hibernate query

```
sqlQuery= SELECT student_name, math + eng + lang from subject
```

Can anyone throw some light on how to get math + eng + lang?

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession
                        .createCriteria(subject.class);
                ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
                projList.add(Projections.property("student_name"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried ANYTHING yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an option in hibernate creteria query but alternatevely you can achive the same by having a method in calss Subject to calculate sum

```
class Subject {
   ....
   public double getTotal() {
      return math + eng + lang;
   }

}
```

Another one option is to use [Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation. You can check this [example](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation)

```
class Subject {
    ....
    @Formula("math + eng + lang")
    private double total
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an SQL projection. It should be something like:

```
session.createCriteria(subject.class) 
        .createAlias("subject", "i") 
        .setProjection( Projections.projectionList() 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.student_name") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.math") )
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.eng") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.lang") ) 
            .add( Projections.sqlProjection( 
                    "math + eng + lang as total", 
                    new String[] { "total" }, 
                    new Type[] { Hibernate.DOUBLE } 
                  ) 
            ) 
        );
```